# Quazrt.net 3.0 + net.core 2.0 : trigger not fire

Tags: c#, quartz.net, quartz.net-3.0

I'm trying to create trigger and start job using quartz.net 3.0 in my net core app. 
Here is a code :
mycontroller.cs

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateHomeWorkReminder([FromBody] CreateHomeWorkReminderRequest request)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    _logger.LogInformation("data valid");
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, object> { {nameof(CreateHomeWorkReminderRequest.UserId), request.UserId },
    {nameof(CreateHomeWorkReminderRequest.HomeWorkId), request.HomeWorkId}};
    await _registerJob.CreateJob<ReminderJob>(nameof(CreateHomeWorkReminder), dict, request.DateOfReminder);
    _logger.LogInformation("saving ok");
    return Ok(result.Result);
}
```

RegisterJob.cs (DI in contructor in mycontroller.cs) :

```
public class RegisterJob : IRegisterJob
{
    ISchedulerBot bot;

    public async Task CreateJob<T>(string jobName, IDictionary<string, object> map, DateTime dateOfReminder) where T : IJob
    {
        NameValueCollection props = new NameValueCollection
{
    { "quartz.serializer.type", "binary" }
};
        StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(props);

        // get a scheduler
        IScheduler sched = await factory.GetScheduler();
        await sched.Start();
        var job = JobBuilder.Create<ReminderJob>().Build();

        var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().StartNow().Build();
        await sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
}
```

}

and ReminderJob.cs

```
   public class ReminderJob : IJob
{
    ILogger<ReminderJob> logger;
    public ReminderJob(ILogger<ReminderJob> _logger)
    {
        logger = _logger;
    }

    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        var parameters = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap;
        var userId = parameters.GetLongValue("UserId");
        var homeWorkId = parameters.GetLongValue("HomeWorkId");
        logger.LogInformation($"userId = {userId}, homeWorkId = {homeWorkId}");
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to debug my code, but never go to the Execute method of ReminderJob.cs. Where is my mistake? What should I to execute job? Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right answer : it's impossible to use DI with Quartz 3.0. I deleted constructor in ReminderJob with DI of ILogger and code worked.

```
public class ReminderJob : IJob
{
    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        var parameters = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap;
        var userId = parameters.GetLongValue("UserId");
        var homeWorkId = parameters.GetLongValue("HomeWorkId");
        await System.Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("HelloJob is executing.");
    }
```